# I don't know what is going on, but someone is intentionally downvoting me

Tags: support, down-votes, serial-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

There is a [series of sudden downvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1172872/sk8terboi87?tab=reputation) made continuously even to my replies/answers (even when the answers were marked as the "correct" anwser).

I know someone is doing it intentionally. What is going on?

Comment: @Yannis Hmm, you're right. That should normally have been caught. Still a dupe, but worth some attention.

Comment: Thx u guys! for looking into.

Comment: I can't find anything suspicious. I may have to check this with the higher-ups.

Answer (score 2):

There is possibly something wrong.

This answer: [Get slug and write content with dashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039732/get-slug-and-write-content-with-dashes/14039784#14039784) has one upvote and a downvote. But on your reputation tab it shows two downvotes and a single upvote.  So maybe some votes are counted twice?

Comment: what I'm wondering is, all those answers are I've made are lil long ago.

Comment: Sometimes there are strange voting patterns. But don't let them discourage you.

Comment: Yes, ur right! Thanks @Toon

Comment: @Sk8terboi - During the last couple of days I have got several surprise votes (upvotes, fortunately) on post from early 2011. Perhaps some archeologists are at work? Odd things happen.

Answer (score -2):

The accepted answer on [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126857/195231) provides a very good explanation to it. I think you might be the victim of the third section of it, ***When does serial downvoting occur?***

As now the 24 hours have been passed and no action is still taken, you could flag one of your posts for moderator attention. they could very well handle the issue.

Comment: Hope so! thx for the reply

Comment: No point in copy pasting an answer from a question that has _already_ been identified as a possible duplicate. Also, he _has_ waited for at least 24 hours, yesterday's downvotes weren't reversed.

Comment: @Yannis removed copied content.